# How can I restore the \" after passing through fputcsv function

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I am working on an sms `API` to send sms batch from my Application. I start by using the following two functions to generate `CSV`.

```
if (!function_exists('output_csv')){
    function output_csv($header, $csv_array)
    {
        $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        //put csv header
        fputcsv($out, $header);

        //Put csv content rows
        foreach ($csv_array as $row) {
            fputcsv($out, $row);
        }
        fclose($out);
    }
}

if (!function_exists('get_csv')){
    function get_csv($header, $csv_array)
    {
        ob_start();
        output_csv($header, $csv_array);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

When I pass an array with quoted string to `get_csv()`function, I get something like this:

> msisdn,message
>
> 111111111,"Hi there"
>
> 333333333,"""Hello""again"

And then, I take the CSV string and pass through `url_encode()` function which outputs the following:

> msisdn%2Cmessage%0A111111111%2C%22Hi+there%22%0A333333333%2C%22%22%22Hello%22%22again%22%0A

This breaks the sms and sends up to the part before the double quotation marks.

In the API example, it was proposed that the encoded string should look like:

> msisdn,message%0a%22111111111%22,%22Hi+there%22%0a%22333333333%22,%22Hello+again.+Here+is+some+%5C%22quoted+text%5C%22.%5C%0aThis+text+follows+a+newline%22

**Note a backslash %5C before %22.**

In my case, the backslash is removed after passing through the fputcsv

I am afraid to use `str_replace` because it may misbehave in some cases where there are three/four consecutive double quotes. 
What is the best way to restore my escaped " after passing through the `fputcsv` function?

Comment: Why are you using `fputcsv` here to begin with? Does the API explicitly demand data “in CSV format”, or what?

Comment: This is what is written in the original API documentation-------->The batch_data CSV field looks like this unencoded:

msisdn,message
"111111111","Hi there"
"333333333","Hello again"

Comment: And what does it says about how double quotes inside the message content should be treated?

Comment: They only provide sample in the url string. Here is Sample quoted text in the url string: %5C%22quoted+text%5C%22, in which the %5C represents \ and %22 represents ".

Comment: Well then I’d not use fputcsv at all, and simply replace each double quote with `\"`. And if you don’t know if that will behave correctly if there are multiple double quotes … well, then do a few tests.